# Is there a way to rebind copy and paste keyboard shortcuts on a PC so that it matches the mac shortcut? Or vice versa?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

For my job I use both a Mac and a PC and am frequently switching between them. So it's probably understandable that sometimes my fingers forget which machine they're typing on and try to use the wrong shortcut.

If I could rebind it so copy and paste on my PC is alt+c/v instead, that would be amazing.

I'm guessing it's likely not possible/practical though.

But I thought it's worth asking here!

Thanks all

-E

Comment: Just learn the difference. Trying to rebind global commands is possible, but impacts so much more than just the ones you want to replace that it quickly becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally in the same position. I've been using "PowerToys Keyboard Manager". You can find more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager

PowerToys is very useful and contains a lot of good stuff, check it out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/